# I'm recieving "Error while extracting response for type" when I try to return the JSON as an Object. How can I solve this?

Tags: java, spring, api, rest, resttemplate

I'm doing an API that consumes an external API (https://swapi.dev/), but I'm receving this error when I try to return the JSON converted to Object.

I'm trying to solve this for almost 12 hours without any success x_x

```
Error while extracting response for type [class [Lcom.starwarsapi.filmsapi.model.FilmModel;] and content type [application/json]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `[Lcom.starwarsapi.filmsapi.model.FilmModel;` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`);
```

---

FilmController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/films")
public class FilmController {

    @Autowired
    private FilmService filmService;

    @GetMapping
    public List<FilmModel> getAllFilms() {
        List<FilmModel> response = filmService.getAllFilms();
        return response;
    }
```

FilmModel:

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class FilmModel {
    private FilmResultModel[] results;
}
```

FilmResultModel

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class FilmResultModel {
    private String title;

    @JsonProperty("episode_id")
    private Integer episodeId;

    @JsonProperty("opening_crawl")
    private String description;

    private String director;
    private String producer;

    @JsonProperty("release_date")
    private String releaseData;

    private String[] characters;
    private String[] planets;
    private String[] starships;
    private String[] vehicles;
    private String[] species;
    private String created;
    private String edited;
    private String url;
```

FilmService:

```
public interface FilmService {
    public List<FilmModel> getAllFilms();
}
```

FilmServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class FilmServiceImpl implements FilmService {

    @Value("${external.api.url}")
    private String filmBaseUrl;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Override
    public List<FilmModel> getAllFilms() {
        FilmModel[] result = restTemplate.getForObject(filmBaseUrl, FilmModel[].class);
        List<FilmModel> films = Arrays.asList(result);
        System.out.println(films);
        return films;
    }
```

PS¹: `external.api.url` = https://swapi.dev/api/films/?format=json

PS²: When I return `getAllFilms` as String, the program works:

```
@Override
public String getAllFilms() {
    String result = restTemplate.getForObject(filmBaseUrl, String.class);
    System.out.println(result);

    return result;
}
```

But I need it to return as an object because later I'll try to create a PUT method to change the description of the movie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `FilmModel result = restTemplate.getForObject(filmBaseUrl, FilmModel.class);`

FilmModel is just the outer wrapper object and contains the list of films.

Comment: It worked now! Yea, my endpoint is returning a FilmModel, not an array of FilmModel... Thank you! :)